# Discord.py - how do i make my discord bot display a typing status

Tags: python, discord, pycharm, discord.py

i have looked at other similar questions and tried to apply them to my issue but none of them worked

im using discord.py to try to give my bot a typing status. i have looked at the documentation but nothing seems to work here as explained later (this is just a small part of the script. [the full thing can be downloaded here)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nqF_2dI4Zr7NRN0ebHef0-5GKa4iujYq?usp=share_link)

```
greetings=[
    "heyyyyyyy",
    "mm hello",
    "sup",
    "HI!!!",
]


def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message
    words=p_message.split()
    
    #for debugging
    print(words)

    if "hey" in words:
        time.sleep(2)
        #trying to implement the typing here
        random_resp=random.choice(greetings)
        return random_resp
```

i have tried this

```
if "hey" in words:
    async with channel.typing():
        # simulate something heavy
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    time.sleep(2)
    random_resp=random.choice(greetings)
    return random_resp
```

and got this error

```
    async with channel.typing():
    ^
SyntaxError: 'async with' outside async function
```

i also tried this and got no error but no typing status either

```
def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message
    words=p_message.split()

    #for debugging
    print(words)

    async def on_message(message):
        async with message.channel.typing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    if "hey" in words:
        time.sleep(2)
        random_resp=random.choice(greetings)
        return random_resp
```

again the full script(s) can be [downloaded here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nqF_2dI4Zr7NRN0ebHef0-5GKa4iujYq?usp=share_link) so you can get a better idea of whats going on.

new to discord python so i should mention a few final things:

- still pretty new to coding in general so i dont understand many terms
- using pycharm as my IDE
- coming from another stack exchange site where the more info about your problem the better

EDIT : this also does not work

in bot.by i have this

```
async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
    try:
        response = await responses.handle_response(user_message)
        await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)
```

and in responses.py i have this

```
greetings=[
    "heyyyyyyy",
    "mm hello",
    "sup",
    "HI!!!",
]

async def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message
    words=p_message.split()

    #for debugging
    print(words)

    if "hey" in words:
        async def on_message(message):
            async with message.channel.typing():
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
        time.sleep(2)
        random_resp=random.choice(greetings)
        return random_resp
```

no error is given but again no typing status is either

Comment: add async to the beginning of your function definition. so 
async def handle_response(message) -> str:
That will make it an async function and it will fix your syntax error and allow the function to work.

Comment: I would also recommend looking into what the Asynchronous library does would help clear up a lot of future problems you may have.

Comment: tried that but it gave me a big error that started with RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'handle_response' was never awaited           said it was an issue with another script i am using "bot.py"

Comment: Okay, I will take a deeper look at it right now also please remove your discord bot token that's something that you should never post publicly. That will give people access to connecting to your discord bot and running whatever they want.

Comment: planned to do a token reset after this because its only used in that one place. its fixed though

Comment: response = responses.handle_response(user_message) this call is not asynchronous you would have to do an await here to make it an asynchronous call so response = await responses.handle_response() alongside that async in front of the def handle_response()

Comment: that diddnt seem to do the trick. edited my question to show what i did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250712/discussion-between-desperrrr-and-somesimpleton).